# Azure AD as Idp in Cognito with OIDC - live.login page not found 404

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I have integrated via OIDC Azure AD as an third party identity provider in AWS Cognito User Pool.

The problem is the microsoft login page is acting awfully random.

When entering valid credentials for user that is in the AD the flow works as expected.

The problem is when i am entering invalid credentials (even a dummy one like "aaaaaa"). In that case i get the This login.live.com page can’t be found page, 404. 
[image: actual]

I would expect to get :

[image: expected]

In some cases i get the valid error message but mostly not.

Comment: do you have found any solution?